# xpath not fetching all links

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a scraper to fetch all the links from my local website.

I am using this selector to fetch all the href values of all anchor tags:

```
response.xpath('//a/@href')
```

The result I am getting is:

```
[<Selector xpath='//a/@href' data=u'index.php'>,
 <Selector xpath='//a/@href' data=u'membership_passwordReset.php'>,
 <Selector xpath='//a/@href' data=u'https://bigprof.com/appgini/'>]
```

The problem is there is another anchor tag on the page with href = `'admin/pageHome.php'` which is not coming in results.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am attaching the page source code screenshot for reference. [image: Source code of the page showing the href tag which is not showing]

Comment: Are those missing links added to the page via Javascript?

Comment: Open this specific page with [`scrapy shell`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) and test your XPath in there. The HTML available there is what Scrapy sees.

Comment: @malberts: When I call fetch(url) from scrapy shell, the page is loaded and we can then fetch the tags. The links should be visible by that time in the HTML itself.

Comment: When you do that in scrapy shell, run the command `view(response)` to inspect the resulting HTML. Is it already in there?

Comment: I checked it in response.body and there it is not present.

Comment: So that means it's either loading with Javascript, or it's returning the wrong page/content. If it's Javascript-based, then you need to use [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to render it. Scrapy does not execute any Javascript by itself. However, if you're getting the wrong page/content, then you first need to debug why that is happening.

Comment: You should refer to this https://medium.com/@yashpokar/scrape-any-website-in-the-internet-without-using-splash-or-selenium-68a6c9733369